# Передача сообщений между процессами

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, wxpython

Python 3.4. GUI - WxPython

Имеется локальный сервер на Flask. На сервере крутится страничка, которая каждую секунду опрашивает БД. Помимо этого, на страничке имеются средства управления, например, кнопка, при нажатии на которую в БД отправляется значение (true/false).

Обработка события нажатия на кнопку (в JS вызывается POST запрос с параметрами кнопки, это дело ловит сервер).

```
@app.route('/set-data', methods=['POST'])
def set():
    data = request.get_data().decode('utf-8')
    set_data(data, inout_folder)
    return json.dumps({'success': True}, 200, {'ContentType': 'application/json'})
```

Как я выше написал, сервер опрашивает БД. Эту БД я могу менять из своей GUI программы.

В итоге имеем: запускается сервер, значения в БД установлены по умолчанию (например, все кнопки выклюены). Я могу из свой программы поменять значение (состояние) какой-то кнопки в БД, следовательно, в момент следующего опроса сервер обнаружит новое значение и отобразит эффект нажатия кнопки.

Сервер запускается в отдельном процессе(чтобы GUI работало). Выглядит это так:

```
            # Запустить локальный сервер
            from multiprocessing import Process
            server = Process(target=ds.run, args=())
            server.start()

            monVars = self.prjCtrl.GetMonVarsWithGroups()
            dlg = Dialogs.SignalInspector(self.IDEFrame, self.prjCtrl.MnemoIds, monVars, debug=True)
            res = dlg.ShowModal()
            if res == wx.ID_OK:
                attrs = dlg.GetAttributes()
                self.prjCtrl.UpdateAttrs(attrs)

            # Остановить локальный сервер   
            server.terminate()
            server.join()
```

Т.е.:

1) Запустить сервер Flask.

2) Открыть диалог, в котором можно менять БД. (через requests послать post запрос /set-data)

3) После закрытия диалога остановить сервер.

Выходит, что состояние кнопки можно изменить из диалога и на страничке (кликнув на нее). С изменением состояния через диалог все отлично. Но не получается реализовать следующий механизм: изменение состояния кнопки через клац на страничке должно приводить к изменению состояния кнопки в диалоге.

Я могу отследить в процессе сервера нажатие кнопки (и какой именно). Но как передать это в диалог (ведь диалог сам является процессом-потомком, т.к. dlg.ShowModal() приостанавливает выполнение основного процесса - wx.App())?

Comment: `from multiprocessing import Process` ну не в потоке, а в процессе

Comment: @gil9red поправлю)

Comment: Либо используйте `from multiprocessing.dummy import ...` для отправки в другой поток, а не процесс